# Set trigger on box.info fields changed in tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I need to catch changing box.info.status from "loading" to "ready". So i can enable my triggers after WAL read, but before replication sync.

My trigger function on `box.space.myspace`:

```
local function before_replace(old, new)
    -- collision resolving here
    if box.session.type() ~= 'applier' then
        box.space.stat:upsert(
            { "key", 0 },
            {
                {"+", stat.COUNT, 1}
            })
    end
    return
end
```

- If i set trigger on schema initialization, it fails with read_only
  error. While trying to upsert read_only `stat` space.
- If i set it on `box.info.ro == False` it skips replication_sync.

I found that most suitable time to set up trigger is a moment then `box.info.status` changed from `loading` to `running`. I solve my problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734280/conflict-resolution-in-tarantool-how-to-fix-replication-in-master-master-mode-i/57396028#57396028). But i'm wonder if where is a better way?

I thought about setting callback function on `box.info.status` field changed. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. There is box.ctl.wait_ro() if you want to wait until an instance leaves the read-only mode. If you want to wait bootstrap end, put your code right after box.cfg. Finally, if you want to catch the event of schema initialization, you set box.ctl.on_schema_init trigger. 
Please describe what exactly you are trying to accomplish and there will be an appropriate instrument for it.

Comment: I fixed the description. Wondering if where is a more suitable tool?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest hack I can think of is spawning a fiber that periodically checks for changes and runs the call back when it detects them.